# Overriding delete method in django model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Page model that during the saving of objects calls the print within the save method. However, when objects are being deleted, no prints are triggered, and it seems like the delete method is never being called. How should I override the default delete method then?

```
class Page(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def get_upload_path(self, filename):
        work_slug = self.chapter.volume.work.slug
        translator_name = slugify(self.chapter.volume.translator)
        volume_number = self.chapter.volume.number
        chapter_number = self.chapter.number
        name, extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)
        return f'media/{work_slug}/{translator_name}/volumes/volume-{volume_number}/chapters/chapter-{chapter_number}/page-{self.number}.{extension}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            last_page = self.chapter.page_set.last()
            if last_page:
                self.number = last_page.number + 1
        self.image.name = self.get_upload_path(self.image.name)
        self.image.storage = s3
        print(f"Saving Page with image: {self.image.name}")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Deleting Page with image: {self.image.name}")

        image_name = self.image.name
        try:
            s3.delete(image_name)
            print(f"Successfully deleted from S3: {image_name}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error deleting from S3: {e}")

        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `delete` method of Model called when one object deleted. if you try to delete a QuerySet (like delete from django admin list page) you must override Model's QuerySet.

```
class PageQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def delete(self):
        print("deleting queryset")
        return super().delete()


class PageManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return PageQuerySet(model=self.model, using=self._db, hints=self._hints)


class Page(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField()
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    chapter = models.ForeignKey(Chapter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = PageManager()

    def get_upload_path(self, filename):
        work_slug = self.chapter.volume.work.slug
        translator_name = slugify(self.chapter.volume.translator)
        volume_number = self.chapter.volume.number
        chapter_number = self.chapter.number
        name, extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)
        return f'media/{work_slug}/{translator_name}/volumes/volume-{volume_number}/chapters/chapter-{chapter_number}/page-{self.number}.{extension}'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            last_page = self.chapter.page_set.last()
            if last_page:
                self.number = last_page.number + 1
        self.image.name = self.get_upload_path(self.image.name)
        self.image.storage = s3
        print(f"Saving Page with image: {self.image.name}")
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"Deleting Page with image: {self.image.name}")

        image_name = self.image.name
        try:
            s3.delete(image_name)
            print(f"Successfully deleted from S3: {image_name}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error deleting from S3: {e}")

        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```